# how to keep data added to a list on a method for all the class java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parse-platform, scope

I need to use the data that i add to my ArrayList fieldsImages outside the method where i add data to it, when i request the data of the fieldsImages inside the 'done' method, it works correctly because the data is there, but outside that method, the fieldsImages it has no data, it's empty.

How can i make the data added to fieldsImages inside the method done stay in it for all the class ?

please note that my 'done' method is nested inside another 'done' method.
those methods are from Parse.com (backend that i am using for the project)

```
    public class ChooseFieldDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        List<String> fieldsNamesInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> fieldsTypeInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> fieldsSizeInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

        //THIS ONE IS THE LIST THAT I NEED TO KEEP THE DATA ADDED ON THE METHOD DONE
        List<Integer> fieldsImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        ListView chooseFieldList;
        String mTitle;
        Long mTime;
        String mVenueId;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            mTitle = bundle.getString("venueName");
            mTime = bundle.getLong("reservTime");
            mVenueId = bundle.getString("venueId");



            setShowsDialog(false);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_field_list, container, false);


            chooseFieldList = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.chooseFragmentList);



                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Field");

                ParseObject fieldObj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Venue", mVenueId);
                query.whereEqualTo("venueId", fieldObj);
                query.setLimit(1000);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(final List<ParseObject> fieldList, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {



                            for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.size(); i++){
                                fieldsNamesInfo.add(fieldList.get(i).getString("name"));
                                fieldsTypeInfo.add(fieldList.get(i).getString("type"));
                                fieldsSizeInfo.add(fieldList.get(i).getString("size"));


                                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Reservation");

                                final ParseObject fieldObj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Field", fieldList.get(i).getObjectId());
                                query.whereEqualTo("fieldId", fieldObj);
                                query.whereEqualTo("date", mTime);
                                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                    public void done(final List<ParseObject> reservForFieldList, ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {

                                            Log.d("FUNCIONO", Integer.toString(reservForFieldList.size()));

                                            if (reservForFieldList.isEmpty()){
                                                Log.d("argegandoVerde","aaaaa");
    //HERE I ADD DATA TO THE LIST                                            fieldsImages.add(R.drawable.onfield);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                Log.d("argegandoGris","uuuuu");

    //HERE I ADD DATA TO THE LIST                                            fieldsImages.add(R.drawable.offfield);

                                            }




                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("venue", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                        }
        //HERE THE ARRAY LIST fieldsImages IS CORRECTLY POPULATED WITH MY DATA

                                    }
                                });

//HERE MY ARRAY LIST LOSES THE DATA AND GETS EMPTY

                                Log.d("qqqqqq", Integer.toString(fieldsImages.size()));


                            }


                            Log.d("qqqqqq", Integer.toString(fieldsImages.size()));





    //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO USE THE DATA THAT I ADDED TO THE ARRAY LIST fieldsImages BUT AT THIS POINT IT IS EMPTY.
                            ChooseFieldCustomAdapter customAdapter = new ChooseFieldCustomAdapter(getContext(), fieldsNamesInfo, fieldsImages, fieldsTypeInfo);
                            chooseFieldList.setAdapter(customAdapter);


                        } else {
                            Log.d("venue", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle(mTitle);
                alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
                alertDialog.show();


                return dialogView;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I make sense your focus, but you want to keep the data of the fieldsImages list? If so, declare the fieldsImage list as static and put the data.
After that, you can use it anywhere. Good luck!

Comment: I would not recommend storing that List as a static member. If you want to you can write an accessor method to return that outside the dialog (eg, `public List<Integer> getFieldImages(){ return this.fieldImages; }`. Given that statics are class level members, one will run into problems with either null or incorrect references. The above method can then be called outside in an activity or other fragment with an unsafe cast `((ChooseFieldDialogFragment)fragment).getFieldImages();`

Comment: I agree with you, Selecsosi. Using as a static is not good for system. I also wonder if there Is any good method for that.